# WMIC uninstall using name and version

Tags: installation, uninstallation, wmic

I have two applications (old and new) which use an identical product name (this cannot be changed). I need to uninstall only the old one but am having trouble including the version with:

```
wmic product where name="AppName" call uninstall
```

How can I use both name and version to uninstall?

Version is unique to the specific old vs new application I'm trying to uninstall, but may not be unique on the local machine an calling to uninstall using the version only will remove everything with a matching version number - something I cant do :)

This is all being executed by an installer for the new application (looking for the old one, asking to uninstall, etc).

Comment: Issue was syntax in formatting the where clause.

should be as follows:

    WMIC product where "name='appname' and version='12345'" call uninstall

WOOT it works! /noob